# How to permanently enable desktop mode on a browser app?

Tags: browser, tablet, browser-add-ons

The tablet is brand new so rooted methods are not an option. I seem to remember there being a Firefox add on that had a similar function, which is now dead and and buried. Are there any other tricks out there?

Comment: Try the solution I gave to another question.
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189824/137930

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to switch from Firefox to an another browser, I suggest you pick any one of the following:

- [Puffin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinFree)
- [Opera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser)
- [Lightning](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=acr.browser.barebones)

The said browsers feature *inter alia* universal *user agent/ website preference* for websites visited and also permits overrides per website. I have tested all of them in Desktop mode.

**Note** that Opera may require a restart of itself for settings to take effect.